# Youtube получить количество просмотров у ролика

Tags: php, youtube-api

Пробовал несколько вариантов.

1:

```
$url_content = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=$video_ID&key=$api_key&part=statistics";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url_content);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
```

2:

```
$contents = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id={$video_id}&key={$api_key}&part=snippet,statistics");
```

3:

```
$option = array(
    'id' => $video_id,
    'key' => $api_key,
    'part' => 'statistics'
);
$url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?".http_build_query($option, 'a', '&');


$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$json_response = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
```

Ошибка одна и тажа:

```
Array
(
    [0] => https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=VID&key=KEY&part=statistics
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [error] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [errors] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [domain] => usageLimits
                                    [reason] => ipRefererBlocked
                                    [message] => There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.
                                    [extendedHelp] => https://console.developers.google.com
                                )

                        )

                    [code] => 403
                    [message] => There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.
                )

        )

)
```

При всем при том, что через `$.ajax` отработало на ура.

Подскажи как получить из PHP скрипта?

**UPD**
Запрос с того же хоста, но через JS:

```
<script>
    function fillOnTheVID(vid){
        var key = 'MY_KEY';
        var urlReq = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id='+vid+'&key='+key+'&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics';
        console.log("Request URI:",urlReq);
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            ///dataType: "JSON",
            ///dataType: "html",
            url: urlReq,
            data: { b:true }
        }).done(function( res ){
            console.log("Response Data:",res);
            var $form = $('form')
                ,item = res.items[0]
            ///,duration = item.contentDetails.duration
                ,author = item.snippet.channelTitle
                ,add = item.snippet.publishedAt
                ,title = item.snippet.title
                ,views = item.statistics.viewCount
                ;
            $form.find('input[name="vid"]').val(vid);
            $form.find('input[name="url"]').val('https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+vid);
            $form.find('input[name="author"]').val(author);
            $form.find('input[name="add"]').val(add);
            $form.find('textarea[name="title"]').val(title);
            $form.find('input[name="views"]').val(views);
        }).error(function(e){
            console.log("Response Errors:",e);
            return -2;
        }).fail(function(e){
            ///console.log("Response Fail:",e);
            ///return -3;
        }).always(function(){
            ///console.log( "Response Always" );
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Так ведь написано же, что IP-адрес заблокирован, поскольку не удовлетворяет требованиям API.

Comment: Спасибо, я примерно догадался, о чем там написано. Будет полезно, если подскажите, почему через JS работает, а через PHP нет. Чего добавить, что бы получить результат. Оба варианта выполняются с одного IP.

Comment: Через JS как делаете – тоже с указанием API KEY? С того же IP, что и PHP?

Comment: Да, добавил код под **UPD**

Comment: По-моему ответ на примерно такую же проблему, дан тут [SoEN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29123516/google-urlshortener-api-returns-iprefererblocked)

Comment: Почти. Я уже на вводил этих IP-шек целую тучу, в разных вариантах и комбинация. Но отличие окна, комментариев к нему и общая идея подачи формы натолкнула на мысль. Вылил ответом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Гадать на кофейной гуще нет смысла.
Спасибо, всем принявшим участие.
На мысль навел комментарий @LamerXaKer
Возможно я невнимательно подошел в вопросу.
Вся информация в интернете для старых интерфейсов.

Есть 4-е вида ключа:
1. Server key
2. Browser key
3. Android key
4. iOS key

[image: Новый интерфейс]

У меня был сгенерирован 2-й ключ, так как работаю в браузере, вроде логично!
*Мне просто надоело выдергивать данные в ручную, вот и навоял скриптец на JS*.

Все отлично работает, но данные загруженные в бд, особенно просмотры, статичны.

Было принято решение написать скриптец, который по крону или требованию будет обновлять просмотры.

И вот как то оно из головы то вылетело:

> PHP работает на стороне сервера
>   Javascript работает на стороне клиента

Для работы в PHP нужно сгенерировать 1-й ключ!

И кратенько:

> Server key for PHP
>   Browser key for Javascript

Надеюсь кому то пригодится...

Answer (score 0):

Можно посмотреть, как, вроде бы решили проблему здесь [SoEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28325010/google-translate-api-returns-403-php)

```
Thanks for admins, they helped to figure out. By default - curl using our ipv6 address...

So we have three options here:

 1. curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE, CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4 );
 2. add ipv6 address to allowed list
 3. Turn ipv6 off forthe server    

I had to be more attentive and remember about ipv6 :-)
```

(C) Scarecrow